# JSON::ParseError (822: unexpected token at '"')

Tags: json, ruby

I am using JSON in Ruby and every time I run the program, I get the error of "unexpected token at." I am not sure what is going on, I tried reading information from other users that had the same problem, but I do not seem to figure out what is going on.

This is my code for my .rb page:

```
def show
  URI.parse('http://robotrevolution.net/interface/int_order_options.php')
  http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  http.use_ssl = false
  http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER

  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, initheader = {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})

  request.basic_auth 'username', 'password'
  response = http.request(request)

  if response.code == "200"
    result = response.body.to_json.first
    @oc_order_options =  JSON.parse(result, :quirks_mode => true)
  else
    "ERROR"
  end
  return @oc_order_options
end
```

And this is the code for my show page:

```
<h1> Display </h1>

<%= @oc_order_options['name'][0]['value'] %>
```

I really appreciate any responses that help me figure out what is going on, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here:

```
result = response.body.to_json.first
```

Try to put `puts response.body.inspect` immediately before this line, figure out what the data is coming back and modify the line above accordingly so that the next line

```
JSON.parse(result, :quirks_mode => true)
```

will succeed.

Comment: Thanks for you response. When I did that, it displayed me all the data present in the database's website and then it displayed a message of  "401 Unauthorized." Right after that it also displayed the unexpected token at error.

Comment: Now you know what happens and should be able to fix the problem yourself.

Comment: Haha, I really do not know what is going on. May I ask you something? Does the 401 Unauthorized means that it is not authorizing me with the username and password given even though I am able to see all the information?

Comment: Yes, unauthorized means unauthorized.

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

mudasobwa was right,the error was on `result = response.body.to_json.first` the format of the information was already in json - it was like double converting it to json, which it did not like.

So on `JSON.parse(result, :quick_mode => true)` I added .first to this line and got rid of the other one.

So simply put it, it looked like this:

```
def show
 URI.parse('http://robotrevolution.net/interface/int_order_options.php')
 http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
 http.use_ssl = false
 http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER

  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, initheader = {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})

 request.basic_auth 'username', 'password'
 response = http.request(request)

if response.code == "200"
  result = response.body.to_json.first
  @oc_order_options =  JSON.parse(result, :quirks_mode => true)
else
  "ERROR"
end
  return @oc_order_options
```

end

And now it looks like this:

```
def show
 URI.parse('http://robotrevolution.net/interface/int_order_options.php')
 http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
 http.use_ssl = false
 http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER

  request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, initheader = {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})

 request.basic_auth 'username', 'password'
 response = http.request(request)

if response.code == "200"
  result = response.body
  @oc_order_options =  JSON.parse(result, :quirks_mode => true).first
else
  "ERROR"
end
  return @oc_order_options
end
```

Thank you!